# $\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{(1+ |t-y|)^r} \|f(y)\|_{L^1} dy \leq \frac{C}{r-1} \|f\|_{C(\mathbb R, L^1(\mathbb R))}$ for some $r>0$?

Tags: integration, inequality, partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb R \to L^1(\mathbb R):t\mapsto f(t)\in L^1(\mathbb R).$ [So $f(t):\mathbb R \to \mathbb C: x\mapsto f(t)(x)$] Assume that $f$ is continuous with  time variable $t$. Assume that $f$ is nice

> For $t>0,$ Can we say $\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{(1+ |t-y|)^r} \|f(y)\|_{L^1} dy \leq \frac{C}{r-1} \|f\|_{C(\mathbb R, L^1(\mathbb R))}$ for some $r>0$?

Where $C(\mathbb R, L^1(\mathbb R))$ denotes class of continuous functions $f:\mathbb R \to L^1(\mathbb R).$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the norm on the continuous function mapping $\mathbb{R} \to L^1(\mathbb{R})$ I assume you mean the maximum-norm, i.e.
$$ \|f\|_{C(\mathbb{R},L^1(\mathbb{R}))} = \sup_{t\in \mathbb{R}} \|f(t)\|_{L^1(\mathbb{R})} $$

If that is the case, then the answer to your question is yes. Indeed, for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and $r > 1$ one has the estimate:

$$\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{(1+ |t-y|)^r} \|f(y)\|_{L^1} dy \leq \frac{2}{r-1} \|f\|_{C(\mathbb R, L^1(\mathbb R))}.$$

Comment: Thanks. How did get last inequality? Please can you explain a bit?

Comment: Just use Hölder's inequality, pulling out the maximum of $\|f(y)\|_{L^1}$ which is the norm that appears on the RHS and then you are of course left with the $L^1$-norm of the rest of the integrand, which can be calculated to be: $\int_{\mathbb R} \frac{1}{(1+ |t-y|)^r} dy = \frac{2}{r-1}$.